# Auto Delete rows in Excel before import to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to import an excel file to an SQL Server Database.

Concern is SQL Server does not recognize the excel file because the first row contains a title and not the table column headers. The table headers are in row 3.

[image]

The excel file (.xlsx) is a report extraction from the ITSM tool (generates every 30 minutes) saved on a folder path.

From what I've read from the forums, macros can be implemented however the file needs to be opened manually in order for this to take effect.

Is there a way to remove the 2 rows in excel without any manual interaction? I have the general idea on how to automate the import but I would like the Excel file to be in the correct format.

PS. I am using SQL Server 2012 Express

Thanks!

Other Sources:

https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/511902-delete-rows-without-open-files.html

Comment: Hi , I have some other solution . Why not to use power query to connect to sql server and fetch the data . Then you can have refresh and no issue in formatting the table

Comment: hi @YashveerSingh,do you mean SQL Server connecting to the ITSM Database? That's the ideal way of replicating the data however the organization does allow connecting to the ITSM DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a procedure and schedule its execution according to your ITSM tool jobs, to automate this. Use `OPENROWSET` to read excel as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=c:\kunal\test.xlsx',
    'SELECT * FROM [sheet1$A3:Z]'
);
```

Something like this should help you. In the above code, I am skipping first two rows, starting reading from cell A3 of the excel and `HDR=YES` represents that my data has titles.